# Is ObjectContext.SaveChanges ACIDIC?

Tags: entity-framework

As the title suggests, Is the following code acidic, e.g. if I call SaveChanges, will all the Product.Add INSERT statements be executed (or rolled back if there is an error).

```
using(DBEntities ctx = new DBEntities())
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        ctx.Products.Add(new Product("Product " + (i + 1)));
    }

    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792.aspx) states:

> SaveChanges operates within a transaction. SaveChanges will roll back
>   that transaction and throw an exception if any of the dirty
>   ObjectStateEntry objects cannot be persisted.

However looking at the profiler, this doesn't seem to be the case. Am I required to wrap the block with TransactionScope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using(DBEntities ctx = new DBEntities())
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        ctx.Products.Add(new Product("Product " + (i + 1)));
    }
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

This SaveChanges() call will be in a transaction automatically. You won't have to wrap it under a new transactionscope.